# how do i calculate a calculation stored in a string?

Tags: python, math

I have a program where i have an input and want to calculate it (eg input = "3+2**5) and I would like to know if there`s any package to calculate it easily.

`x = "5*70 y = x.calculate() print(y)"`
**just a simple example**

Comment: Is `x.calculate() print(y)` really supposed to be in the string?

Comment: You can use the built-in `eval()` function.

Comment: I would recommend [ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string). And if you look at the comments on the accepted answer to that question, you'll find this package: https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval which was adapted from the answer!

Comment: @MichaelCao `ast.literal_eval` doesn't work for expressions, only literals

Answer (score 0):

Just try function `eval()`
For example:

```
x = "5*70"
print(eval(x))
```

> 350